# How do I re-size Toast UI's React calendar?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to put two components side by side in my React project. The first is a component I coded myself, and the second is a third-party calendar. ([Toast UI's React calendar](https://ui.toast.com/tui-calendar), to be precise.)

[Here](https://github.com/spheroidic/sample-app) is a bare-bones React app I created that shows the problem.

I have tried:

1. Adding a div with a flex display and the default direction set to "row" around both components:

```
// App.js
import "./App.css"
<div className="app">
  <MyComponent />
  <Calendar />
</div>
```

```
// App.css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-default: row;
}
```

2. Changing from flex to grid, with `grid-template-columns` set to 1 fr and 3 fr.

```
// Updated App.css
.app {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}
```

3. Styling each component to `float: left` and `float: right`, with `width: 25%` and `width: 75%`, respectively. With and without a wrapping div.

```
// App.js
import "./App.css"
{/*<div>*/}
  <MyComponent className="list" />
  <Calendar className="mycalendar" />
{/*</div>*/}
```

```
// App.css
.list {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.mycalendar {
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}
```

I'm guessing the problem has to do with the third party calendar. Seems like it just wants to take up the whole page no matter what. I feel like there should be a simple solution though.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question can't be answered without inspecting all CSS applying to each of the children. What you're attempting should be fairly easy and you haven't added any code which would make it problematic.

Comment: I added a sample React app that reproduces the problem. I hope this helps. @tao any thoughts on how I might resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is bootstrap way. remove css if you are trying this.

```
<div className='container'>
   <div className='row'>
     <div className='col'>
       <MyComponent />
     </div>
     <div className='col'>
       <Calendar />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this will give 50% to MyComponent and 50% to Calendar. you can adjust sizing. once go through bootstrap documentation :)

css way:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
.grid-item {
  text-align: center;
}


<div className="grid-container">
  <div className="grid-item"><MyComponent /></div>
  <div className="grid-item"><Calendar /></div>
</div>
```